# CSS Horizontal Menu Problem: Won't Work in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, menu, html-lists

Could you help me fix the menu on this [this page](http://www.efficientcode.com/p/menu.html)?  The menu list items don't have a width defined, so they display at 100% width in IE7.  If I make the span.right have a float: left, it fixes the problem, but then the rounded corners don't work.  A possible solution might be to get rid of the right span and set a padding and background image to the anchor, but that will: a) prevent me from being able use to a background image on the anchor (for this instance, I suppose a solid color will do) and b) require that I break menu.png into separate image files.

If you guys have any good suggestions, let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you include a minimal version of the code in your question, rather than putting part of the question on another web site.

Comment: The other website has the minimal code.  There is no excess code.

Comment: The point is that we should not need to go to another website and do a "view source" in order to understand the problem. Put the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the actual text to the middle, between `<span class="left"></span>` and `<span class="right"></span>`, and encompass it in `<span>` tags:

```
<li><a href="#">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</a></li>
```

You can then add the CSS rule:

```
#menu ul li a span
{
    float: left;
}
```

Then remove `float: left;` from `span.left` and `span.right`. This should work fine on both Firefox and IE 7, and I'm assuming most other browsers too. Of course, this will only work if you're OK with restructuring the HTML a little.

Comment: That messes up the rounded corners (as I said in my post): http://www.efficientcode.com/p/menu2.html